# How to make a simple "Sum" loop faster?

Tags: excel, vba

I am beginning to learn how to use loops and arrays but this one has me stuck. Below is a code that loops through cells and adds them together in column P.

```
Sub Loop_Test()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
lr = Fcst.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    With sht1
        For i = 4 To lr

            .Range("P" & i).Value = Application.Sum(Range("D" & i, "O" & i))

        Next 
    End With

End Sub
```

Overall, this code works but it is very slow and I need to apply it to thousands of rows. I know that in order to make this faster, I need to turn the sum range into an array but I am not entirely sure how to do this when a loop is included.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Disclaimer: I know there are more efficient ways to sum cells together but this is just me playing around and learning.

Comment: what is `Fcst`?

Comment: i edited a few things but it is just supposed to be sheet names

Comment: The slowness comes from you accessing the workbook twice for each iteration of the loop.  If you want to go faster pull in the range to an array, put the sums in a second array and when finished write the sum array in one single go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variant array to limit the number of times that the vba accesses the worksheets:

```
Sub Loop_Test()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim fcst As Worksheet
    Set fcst = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = fcst.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim dta As Variant
    dta = fcst.Range(fcst.Cells(4, "D"), fcst.Cells(lr, "O")).Value

    Dim otpt As Variant
    ReDim otpt(1 To UBound(dta, 1), 1 To 1)

    With sht1
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(dta, 1) To UBound(dta, 1)
            otpt(i, 1) = Application.Sum(Application.Index(dta, i, 0))
        Next i

        .Range("P4").Resize(UBound(dta, 1), 1).Value = otpt
    End With

End Sub
```

---

Edit

The SUM(INDEX()) is slow it is quicker just to add the parts individually.

```
Sub Loop_Test()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim fcst As Worksheet
    Set fcst = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = fcst.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim dta As Variant
    dta = fcst.Range(fcst.Cells(4, "D"), fcst.Cells(lr, "O")).Value

    Dim otpt As Variant
    ReDim otpt(1 To UBound(dta, 1), 1 To 1)

    With sht1
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(dta, 1) To UBound(dta, 1)
            Dim j as Long
            For j = lbound(dta,2) to ubound(dta,2)
                otpt(i, 1) = otpt(i, 1) + dta(i, j) 
            Next j
        Next i

        .Range("P4").Resize(UBound(dta, 1), 1).Value = otpt
    End With

End Sub
```

Tested on 50,000 rows and result was near instantaneous.

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error when setting "dta". I get  "Objec does support this property or method".

Comment: @GSC see edit.  Thats what I get for typing in the answers.

Comment: Hi Scott, the sum value I am getting is only the value equal to the first column "D". It is not summing the values all the way to column "O"

Comment: Yes I also changed that line in the edit.  Make sure you are using the most up to date version of everything

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Just do them all at once. Looping only adds time to process individual iterations.

```
With sht1.Range(sht1.cells(4, "P"), sht1.cells(lr, "P"))

    .formula = "=sum(D4:O4)"
    .Value = .value

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping over each row you can insert a summation formula into each row of column P with a single line of code:

`.Range("P4:P" & lr).Formula="=SUM(D4:O4)"`

assuming 4 is the starting row, and your variable `lr` is the last row.

Answer (score 0):

## Faster With an Array

```
Sub Loop_Test()

    Const cSheet1 As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const cSheet2 As Variant = "Sheet2"
    Const fr As Integer = 4

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim fcst As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vnt As Variant

    Set sht1 = Worksheets(cSheet1)
    Set fcst = Worksheets(cSheet2)

    With fcst

        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        ReDim vnt(1 To lr - fr + 1, 1 To 1)

        For i = 1 To UBound(vnt)
            vnt(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum( _
                    .Range("D" & i + fr - 1, "O" & i + fr - 1))
        Next

    End With

    sht1.Cells(fr, "P").Resize(UBound(vnt)) = vnt

End Sub
```

Comment: You are still accessing the sheet ever loop which is slow.  bulk load the data into another array and iterate that.  Two arrays one with the input data and one that holds the output data.  Then you only access the sheet twice not once per every loop.

Comment: @ScottCraner: But the problem is the sum up of the rows of the array. I tried your code. It takes a minute to complete for 10000 records. I've tried user10862412's code, it takes over a second and is slower than mine. I am using Excel 2003 though.

Comment: Interesting, I think it is the sum and index.  let me do some testing.

Comment: It was the SUM(INDEX()). I just edited.  test with 50,000 lines.  It was instantaneous.

Comment: @Now your code would surely use half the time at 100000 lines. Touché. Can it be written more elegantly? What if you had 1000 columns?

Comment: Yes we can loop the columns.

Comment: @But you're slowing down again. Now it is just a little faster than mine. I would revert to the ++++++ version.